# elements with equal centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If centralizer of two elements are equal and the square of one of them belongs to the center of the group, then can we prove that the square of the other element belongs to the center of the group too?

Comment: Interesting question. How did it come up?

Comment: I need it in the middle of proving sth.

Comment: Can you be a little more forthcoming, or are you paying by the word?

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the dihedral group $D_8 = \langle \tau, \sigma | \tau^2, \sigma^8, \tau\sigma\tau = \sigma^{-1} \rangle$. The center is $(e, \sigma^4)$. (Since $e$ and $\sigma^4$ are the only elements in the cyclic subgroup that are their own inverses, so that they commute with the flips as well.)

The centralizer of any non central element in the cyclic subgroup of order 8 is exactly the cyclic subgroup. One of them (say $\sigma^2$) has square in the center, but others, for instance $\sigma$, do not.

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: What don't you understand? You don't understand the definition of $D_8$? You don't understand why the center is as given? You don't understand why the centralizer is as given? You don't understand why there's a cyclic subgroup of order 8? "I do not understand" is not good enough --- you have to help people to help you, by being as explicit as possible about what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: Earth to 151716, come in please --- we'd like to hear from you.

Comment: @user151716 Can we help?